# Django, query filtering from model method

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have these models:

```
def Foo(Models.model):
    size = models.IntegerField()
    # other fields

    def is_active(self):
         if check_condition:
              return True
         else:
              return False

def Bar(Models.model):
     foo = models.ForeignKey("Foo")
     # other fields
```

Now I want to query Bars that are having active Foo's as such:

```
Bar.objects.filter(foo.is_active())
```

I am getting error such as

```
SyntaxError at /
('non-keyword arg after keyword arg'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You cannot query against model methods or properties. Either use the criteria within it in the query, or filter in Python using a list comprehension or genex.

Comment: Or store the value you want to filter by in a database field and update it when you need to (usually on saving). Then you can filter/sort it just like any other field.

Comment: If I re-use the criteria within the method query, how do I stay DRY? My methods are extremely important to our business logic and if said logic changes, I cannot afford my methods to break. Staying DRY is extremely important.

Answer (score 33):

You could also use a custom manager. Then you could run something like this:

```
Bar.objects.foo_active()
```

And all you have to do is:

```
class BarManager(models.Manager):
    def foo_active(self):
       # use your method to filter results
       return you_custom_queryset
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

Comment: I highlight that this approach would prevent queryset chaining: one could not run python in the custom manager and then add a queryset method, such as `filter` or `exclude`. 

The reason for this is that Django will evaluate the queryset when you run a non-queryset method on it. The queryset consists of SQL commands that will fetch the queried data from the database. In this example, if Django didn't evaluate the queryset to fetch the data from the db, the python method  in this custom manager would have no data to interact with.

Comment: @TD1 That's the valuable remark. Technically, I would say this custom manager method doesn't prevent you from queryset chaining because you still can use it as a terminal method in chain. But you have to keep that in mind so it could be error-prone.

Answer (score 26):

I had similar problem: I am using class-based view `object_list` and I had to filter by model's method. (storing the information in database wasn't an option because the property was based on time and I would have to create a cronjob and/or... *no way*)

My answer is ineffective and I don't know how it's gonna scale on larger data; but, it works:

```
q = Model.objects.filter(...)...
# here is the trick
q_ids = [o.id for o in q if o.method()]
q = q.filter(id__in=q_ids)
```

Comment: This is the only way I see to stay DRY, however it will hinder performance with larger datasets (remember that lists are stored in memory)

Answer (score 10):

You can't filter on methods, however if the is_active method on Foo checks an attribute on Foo, you can use the double-underscore syntax like `Bar.objects.filter(foo__is_active_attribute=True)`

Comment: I am getting: Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active_attribute' into field Choices are: .... all variable names listed here

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "if the is_active method on Foo checks an attribute...". Filtering only works on database fields, not methods. So if is_active *is checking some attribute inside the method* you can check the same thing in your filter. If it's doing something more complicated, you're outta luck and need to find a different solution. If you want a specific answer, post the real code for Foo.is_active(). Otherwise all you'll get is pseudo-code solutions that you shouldn't expect to work verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, and as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams pointed out, you cannot query against model methods in a view. Instead, I would apply the required filter logic in the view.

For instance, when `check_condition` is a date range:

```
class BarView(ListView):
    model = Bar
    template_name = "app/bar.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Filter for a condition (here the condition is a date range)
        now = timezone.now().date()
        return Bar.objects.filter(foo__start_date__lte=now, foo__end_date__gte=now)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [django-denorm](https://pypi.org/project/django-denorm/) to essentially dynamically create a model field:

```
@denorm.denormalized(models.BooleanField, null=True, default=False)
@denorm.depend_on_related("Bar")
def is_active(self):
    # return something
```

Then you can filter by `foo__is_active=True`.

After adding this, use `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` and `manage.py denorm-init` to prepare the database. This may not be the best solution because models should be primarily representing the database structure, not doing much work themselves, but it's what my predecessor did.