# How to filter a queryset based on the result of a method on the model class that returns a boolean?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

As a member function of one of my model classes, I have an `is_visible(self, user)` method that returns a boolean.  As defined, it takes the requesting user (Django `User` model) as input.

I would like to be able to filter querysets based on the response to this method.  How can I use this function as a queryset filter?

For context, here is my `is_visible` implementation:

```
    def is_visible(self, user):
        if self.status.status_internal == "open":
            return True
        if self.owner == user:
            return true

        participations = Participation.objects.filter(event__id=self.id, participant__id=user.id)
        if len(participations) > 0:
            return True

        if self.status.status_internal == "invite":
            return True

        return False
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django, query filtering from model method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276768/django-query-filtering-from-model-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use python function to filter queryset.  You have to "duplicate" this code and filter your objects using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: `qs.annotate().filter(Q(status__status_internal__in=['open', 'invite']) | Q(owner=True))`

for participations you should do something like `| Q(participation_set__participant_id=user.id)`

Comment: @imposeren Thanks for putting together some actual code samples so that I can see how this would get pulled together.. I'm curious, can a Q object have 2 `_set__` filters in one Q object?  You have noted `Q(participation_set__participant_id=user.id)`, but I'd like it to match `user.id` AND `event__id=self.id`.  I guess this would have to be 2 distinct Q objects?

Comment: ``Q`` queries can be used just as ``qs.filter``: ``model.objects.filter(Q(participation_set__participant_id=user.id, event__id=self.id))`` equals to ``model.objects.filter(Q(participation_set__participant_id=user.id) & Q(event__id=self.id))`` equals to ``model.objects.filter(participation_set__participant_id=user.id, event__id=self.id)``