# Pattern for Django model instance method + equivalent QuerySet filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

This is sort of the inverse of [How to filter a queryset based on the result of a method on the model class that returns a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652223/how-to-filter-a-queryset-based-on-the-result-of-a-method-on-the-model-class-that) -- I want to define a boolean instance method based on the QuerySet filter, or even better define an obviously paired QuerySet filter and boolean instance method.

I've written QuerySet/Manager subclasses to implement custom filtering for various models based on the docs, eg.

```
class MyModelQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def visible_to_user(self, user):
        # Filter logic

class MyModelManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModelQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    def visible_to_user(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().visible_to_user(user)

class MyModel(Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()
```

What I need is something I can call using a model instance.

Currently I'm creating a QuerySet containing only the instance, running the filter on it, and looking at whether anything remains:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()
    def visible_to_user(self, user):
        qs = self.__class__.objects.filter(pk=self.pk)
        if hasattr(qs, 'visible_to_user'):
            return qs.visible_to_user(user).exists()
        return False
```

This is nice and generic (it's actually defined in a mixin so I can use it across all my models) but it's not very efficient -- it re-retrieves the instance from the database every time, and in many cases the filter logic is poorly optimized for the case where there's a single instance.

Simply writing an instance-oriented boolean function on the model would be easy enough, my worry is that this would be tricky to maintain -- basically any change made to one version would have to be reflected in the other, which is more difficult when they're in totally different classes and there's no obvious connection between the two.

One option I've considered is putting both functions in a single mixin, and then each component uses the appropriate version:

```
class VisibleToUserMixin(object):
    def _qs_visible_to_user(self, user):
        # QuerySet logic
    def _instance_visible_to_user(self, user):
        # Instance logic

class MyModelQuerySet(VisibleToUser, QuerySet):
    def visible_to_user(self, user):
        return self._qs_visible_to_user(user)

class MyModel(VisibleToUser, Model):
    def visible_to_user(self, user):
        return self._instance_visible_to_user(user)
```

This adds some baggage for the QuerySet and Model subclasses to wire up, but at least it keeps all the logic in one place where it's easy for maintainers to see the dependency.

Any suggestions for a best practice here?

Comment: Note that since Django 1.7 you don't need to define a separate manager and queryset - just define the queryset, and set the manager as `MyModelQuerySet.as_manager()` - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#creating-manager-with-queryset-methods).

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know when we finally get updated to 1.7 (we are stuck with Python 2.6, thus Django 1.6)

Comment: How complex are your filters? If they're just field/value stuff you could write something that takes a dict of filters and turns them into a set of `filter` arguments in one method, then something else that checks the same field expectations against the model instance.

Comment: Filters are fairly complex in some cases, but I like the idea of using some generic representation that can be defined once and applied appropriately in both methods.