# Django query filter with model method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model code like:

```
class Person:
...

   def is_male(self):
....

   def is_female(self):
....
```

Then, how can I get all the male or female, especially - I just wanted to make a query that getting all males or females.

Comment: you can use django filter.. example persons=Person.objects.all().filter(is_male=1, is_female=0)

Comment: @Tegito123 Thanks - but we can't use model method for filtering and making query.

Comment: other method is by raw sql for custom query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276768/django-query-filtering-from-model-method

Comment: show details of your method code

Comment: Create a field called `sex` with `choices` that associate to male and female, and then check that in the query. Your methods are written in python which SQL can't run as part of the query, which means that django would have to pull down all model instances and then manually check each object which would take forever.