# How to calculate a rank in a property decorator in Django model when the rank is based on another property decorator?

Tags: python, django, properties, python-decorators

I am a new coder and very new to Django/Python.  I am building an application that consolidates results for a rowing race.  I have the following models in models.py.

```
class Crew(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    composite_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='crews',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rowing_CRI = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rowing_CRI_max = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sculling_CRI = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sculling_CRI_max = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='crews',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    penalty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    handicap = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    manual_override_minutes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    manual_override_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    manual_override_hundredths_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bib_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, related_name='bands',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def raw_time(self):
        if len(self.times.filter(tap='Start')) > 1 or len(self.times.filter(tap='Finish')) > 1:
            return 0

        start = self.times.get(tap='Start').time_tap
        end = self.times.get(tap='Finish').time_tap
        return end - start

    @property
    def race_time(self):
        # The race time can include the penalty as by default it is 0
        return self.raw_time + self.penalty*1000

    @property
    def event_band(self):
        if not self.band:
            return self.event.name

        return str(self.event.name) + ' ' + str(self.band.name)

class RaceTime(models.Model):
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    bib_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
    tap = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    time_tap = models.BigIntegerField()
    crew = models.ForeignKey(Crew, related_name='times',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,)
```

I want to create two additional properties.  One that will rank a crew by `race_time()` across all crews and one that will rank crews within their `event_band()`.

Here is my first attempt to create the overall ranking as a property called rank:

```
@property
def rank(self):
    crews = Crew.objects.filter(status__in=('Accepted')).filter(race_time__isnull=False)
    race_times = list(map(lambda crew: crew.race_time, crews)).sort()
    rank = race_times.index(self.race_time) + 1
    return rank
```

This code fails with this error:

Internal Server Error: /api/crews/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/Development/pairshead-results/results/views.py", line 82, in get
    return Response(serializer.data) # send the JSON to the client
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 757, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 261, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 675, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 675, in 
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 513, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 443, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 93, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/Development/pairshead-results/results/models.py", line 63, in rank
    crews = Crew.objects.filter(status__in='Accepted').filter(race_time__isnull=False)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1190, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1049, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/Users/sianalcock/.local/share/virtualenvs/pairshead-results-3ZeqXKPg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1420, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'race_time' into field. Choices are: band, band_id, bib_number, club, club_id, competitors, composite_code, event, event_id, handicap, id, manual_override_hundredths_seconds, manual_override_minutes, manual_override_seconds, name, penalty, raw_time, rowing_CRI, rowing_CRI_max, sculling_CRI, sculling_CRI_max, status, time_only, times
[30/Sep/2019 13:46:08] "GET /api/crews/ HTTP/1.1" 500 23531

Am I even on the right lines here?

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: I have added the entire trace.  It seems that I can't use the Crew.objects.filter on a property decorator.  So I'm now investigating how to create my raw_time and race_time fields as model fields (and to populate them with a calculation).  Any tips greatly appreciated - can't find example in the Django documentation so far.

Comment: Yes you are correct: filter only works on "Field" type attributes. After browsing awhile, it seems like your options are: 1) Do a list comprehension filtering 2) Overwrite model's `save` such that you calculate the `race_time` and store it concretely before you save the instance, instead of calculating it on runtime. If you wish to dig more you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276768/django-query-filtering-from-model-method)

Comment: Thanks @mingjun - I'd like to do option 2 but I'm struggling.  Can you give me a steer on that?

Comment: Let me put it as answer as SO's comment is too limited

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that.  I also saw this package django-computed-property on GitHub which seems to simplify things a bit.

Comment: Ehh, right, that `django-computed-property` does offers a much neater solution than what I have in my mind. I have also tested in on my machine, with `race_time` defined as `ComputedIntegerField`, I can apply `Crew.objects.filter(race_time__isnull=False)` just fine. Subsequently the rank property is also working as expected. You should try that

**Note that you need to have different name for the ComputedIntegerField and the property name where you carry out the calculation**

Let me know how it goes

Comment: I have made the raw_time and race_time fields computed fields and I can see values for them.  But don't think the filters are working for me... I want to use this extended filter Crew.objects.filter(status__in='Accepted').filter(race_time__gt=0).filter(race_time__lt=self.race_time).  In the docs for the django-computed-property it says the querying won't work until you "(re-)save all instances of your data to have the computed fields populated in the database".  Do you know how I do that?  Sorry to keep pestering you....

Comment: Link to documentation https://django-computed-property.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I've removed the computed fields using django-computed-property as they screwed up an import from my API.  I think before I mentioned this package, you were going to post an answer with args/kwargs.. I'd be grateful to see that approach if you are still willing.

Comment: Sure thing. The idea is basically 1) define a concrete fields for your properties like `raw_time` and `race_time`. 2) Override the original `__init__()` function of your `Model`, so that you calculate the value of those properties, whenever you create an instance of that Crew model. 3) Also you have to override the original `save()` function so that it recalculate respective values whenever values are being updated.

Comment: Are you familiar with method overriding in Python? If not I would suggest you look it up first before you proceed. Also the solution is rather verbose as to accustom to your use case. Usually it is enough to just override `save()` function such that properties values are **available after instance are saved**. But in your case some properties are dependent on those properties values, hence we have to make it available after init through overriding `__init__`

Comment: Really appreciate your help @mingjun.  Only just started python but I will research as you suggest.  Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. If throughout the new path you discover a totally new problem feel free to open a new question so that you can attract people with perhaps better expertise and experience, or else we can continue here as well