# Django annotate this?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a function that is present on a field on my model that I would like to sort by. The function (`sort` in the example below) takes the instance of the model as the argument and spits out a value. I need to pass the model instance so that I can get values from fields. I want to sort by the output of the function. I'm trying to do something like:

```py
model.objects.annotate(sort_value=field.sort(this)).order_by(sort_value)
```

How can I reference an individual model instance in the queryset (using `this` as the placeholder in the example)? Should I be using something other than annotate?

Something like:

```py
sorted(model.objects.all(), key=field.sort)
```

but fast.

Comment: If it's a pure Python function, you probably can't do this easily. The ORM isn't magic, it still has to translate to SQL somehow.  If you show the function source, someone might be able to translate it directly to a query, though.

Comment: If you want to sort data while getting it using models. check order by in the orm itself. It will help. If you do it from database, it is expected to be faster, based on indexes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: @Durai not in this case because I want to order based on a function, not necessarily a field

Comment: My understanding is that you want to do a sort based on model property. But not on the fields. If you do that on the fly, it is going to cause you performance issue. So my best bet will you, I will calculate that value on save and store that in the model itself to store in db. Then will perform order by to sort later. This way it will be lot faster. But, if you do update using queryset or update from raw sql, you will face inconsistency. You can use trigger in this case. you can omit save via queryset and write a table level trigger instead row level.

Comment: It is not possible to filter/sort a query by a model method/property in the ORM (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276768/django-query-filtering-from-model-method).  If you post the function we might be able to help create that annotation, which would allow filtering/sorting.